# How to make combo multi axes using d3.js

Tags: d3.js

i'm just newbie in data visualization, but i must try to visualize for some data

i find the combo-multi-axes with highchart.js (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes), it's look perfect to me, but i want make it using d3.js, and i try search referrence for how d3.js can build it, but stil not found

How d3.js can build same like http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes ?

Comment: Try this? http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/using-multiple-axes-for-d3js-graph.html

Comment: it's not same like what i mean :(

Comment: NVD3? http://nvd3.org/examples/linePlusBar.html

Comment: hi @LarsKotthoff!thanks for sharing this,,,it's improved from d3.js right? i will try it...thx :)